# Deleting rows when the dataset is structured to have multiple entries for the categories you're interested in

Tags: r

I'm new to R so I would appreciate any help, and in simple language.

I am working with a dataset about vaccine statistics in different countries--each row is a country.

However, the creator of the dataset made a new row as more updated information came out, meaning there are multiple rows for the same country. There is a column in the dataset that tells me the date that each row was added.

For the purposes of my project, I'd like to delete all rows but the most recent update for each country in the dataset. How can I do this?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow & R programming in general ! As Ronak has pointed out above, it is best practice (required) that you give a reproducible example. This is generally done by calling `dput(head(df), 20)`, where df the name of your `data.frame` (dataset), and copying and pasting the output from your console into your question. Because you are a new contributor, however, please see the below. The sample dataset I have constructed I believe matches yours. As you'll soon learn there are many ways to skin a cat in R, that is why it is such a beautiful language. That being said, please see several alternative solutions to your problem below. Note: `df` should be substituted with the name of your `data.frame`, so should `Country`, `VaccinesAdministered`, and `ReportDate` with the name of your country, vaccine administered number, and date variable:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Country = c("Australia", "New Zealand", "Australia", "New Zealand"),
  VaccinesAdministered = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  ReportDate = as.Date(c("2021-04-08", "2021-04-08", "2021-04-09", "2021-04-10"))
)
    
# Option 1; Subset with subset() & group-wise logical test of maximum dates
# current_vaccinations => data.frame
current_vaccinations <- subset(
  df,
  ReportDate == ave(ReportDate, Country, FUN = max)
)

# Option 2; De-duplicating ordered data:
# current_vaccinations => data.frame
current_vaccinations <- subset(
  with(df, df[rev(order(ReportDate)),]),
  !(duplicated(Country))
)

# Option 3: subsetting using square brackets -- this is the preferred option:
current_vaccinations <- df[
  df$ReportDate == ave(
    df$ReportDate, 
    Country, 
    FUN = max),
]

# Option 4; Filtering the data by group: 
library(dplyr)
# current_vaccinations => tibble
current_vaccinations <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  filter(ReportDate == max(ReportDate)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Option 5; Slicing the data by group: 
library(dplyr)
# current_vaccinations => tibble
current_vaccinations <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  slice(which.max(ReportDate)) %>% 
  ungroup()
  
# Option 6; Data-table Filtering:
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ReportDate == ave(ReportDate, Country, FUN = max), ,]
```